# How to clean auxiliary files within subdirectories with latexmk

Tags: auxiliary-files, latexmk

Well, the title is pretty much self-explanatory but for sake of clarity, I have latex paper with such structure:

```
.
├── back_matter
│   └── some_tex_files.tex
├── bibliography
│   └── bibliography.bib
├── body_matter
│   ├── a_file.tex
│   └── another_file.tex
├── graphics
│   └── some_images.png
├── styles
│   ├── bib_style.bbl
│   └── paper_style.cls
├── paper.tex
└── Makefile
```

And a `Makefile` like so:

```
.PHONY: paper.pdf

all: paper.pdf

paper.pdf: paper.tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interactive=nonstopmode" -use-make paper.tex

clean:
    latexmk -CA
```

`make clean` successfully cleans all the auxiliary files in the `root` (`.`), however, it does not clean the auxiliary files created in the subdirectories. How to define a rule for cleaning all the `.aux` files within the subfolders? I should mention that I use `\input` to add the files to `paper.tex`.

P.S. Is this make file well written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If all the files in the subdirectories are input using `\input`, then there'll be no `.aux` files in the subdirectories.  You will only get such `.aux` files if the running of `pdflatex` on some other file made them or if you used `\include` at some point in the past instead of `\input`.  In any case, they are not part of the files involved in the current run of `pdflatex`, so `latexmk` correctly does not delete them when you do `latexmk -CA`.  On the other hand, if a file is brought into the document by `\include`, then the corresponding `.aux` file is involved in the document, and `latexmk -CA` will delete it.
   If you find some other behavior, we'll need a MWE to understand the problem.
2. As regards the `Makefile`, you should look at the section about this in the `latexmk` documentation.  The relevant section "USING latexmk WITH make' is near the end of the documentation, and there are some options to `latexmk` that are useful.  The important thing is that with a little care, `make` can find all the dependency information that `latexmk` computes.
3. If your description of the project is complete, then a `Makefile` is unnecessary; the command `latexmk` without any arguments will do what you need, particularly if there is only a single `.tex` file in your root directory, and any configuration needed is in a `latexmkrc` file.  A `Makefile` is normally needed only when there are other things you need it to do besides those that `latexmk` is designed to do.

For your case, a suitable `Makefile` is

```
DEPS_DIR = .deps
.PHONY: all clean

# Read in known dependencies:
$(foreach file,$(wildcard $(DEPS_DIR)/*P),$(eval -include $(file)))

all: paper.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex
    @if [ ! -e $(DEPS_DIR) ]; then mkdir $(DEPS_DIR); fi
    latexmk -deps-out=$(DEPS_DIR)/$@P -pdf -dvi- -ps- $<

clean:
    latexmk -C
```

This uses some special features of GNU make.  Dependence information is kept in a subdirectory named `.deps`.

Comment: Indeed you are right about the `.aux` files. I think they belonged to my first try with `\include`. Thanks for comprehensive answer.